# A bug during question listing?

Tags: support

So your  on a hunt to find juicy questions ....
You click on the "unanswered tab"

[image]

Scroll down to the bottom and click on the very last tab (with 50 per page in this example) to get the "oldest"

[image]

Turns out that at least the last 250 + question in the unanswered tab all have answers.  Which means that "unanswered" in this case probably means "sort unaccepted questions from zero answers to many answers". Understandable but not really what "unanswered" means and it makes it harder to service/find the oldest truly unanswered questions.

as pointed out in comments:  There is a difference between ....
[image]

and ... 
[image]
which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Interesting. If you click the actual "Unanswered" button, you get an interface that clearly states "Questions with no upvoted answers" and you can select questions with *no* answers.

Comment: yes, interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the site, "Unanswered" means that there are no upvoted or accepted answers, which means that likely the question didn't receive a proper answer.

Therefore, you might not be the first answering the question, but probably the issue hasn't been solved yet, and the question gets visibility there.